# Unable to align text vertically in programmatically created TextView

Tags: android, textview

I am creating a TextView programmatically that is rendered on a canvas. My code for doing this is:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.layout(0, 0, 140, 180);
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 16);
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
textView.setText("ABC");
textView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

canvas.drawBitmap(textView.getDrawingCache(), scaledX, scaledY, null);
```

But it does not align vertically. I have tried to align it with *Gravity.BOTTOM* also, but with no result. Horizontally aligning the text works with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might need to set your height of TextView. Without setting the height of TextView, it might have a wrapContent height, and hence center_vertical has no impact.

Below is a simple example of setting the height to MatchParent (Make sure there's enough space for it to be taller than the Text font height, so that it have space to vertically centered)

```
textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Comment: Shouldn't the height be set by textView.layout(0, 0, 140, 180)? Since I put the green background there, I can see that the height of it is about three times the height of the text. Tried to set the layoutParams but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: I try change to textView.layout(0, 0, 500, 500), it has no impact. That's not the way to set the width and height I believe. You need to set it through the LayoutParam.